# Cannot Connect to New O365 Group From Existing Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, groups

Our provisioning process is suddenly not working. We usually create an O365 Group after the Team site has been created. But today, I receive this error even with Full Control and set as SCA and Global Administrator. Any ideas on what setting could be stopping me from creating an O365 team?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global admins can create Groups via any means.

If possible, ask another Global admin or SharePoint admin to connect to a new Microsoft 365 Group and check the reuslt.

Or try to Connect sites to new Microsoft 365 groups using PowerShell mentioned in the following article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group?view=sharepoint-ps

More inforamtion:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/let-users-connect-classic-sites-to-groups

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/manage-creation-of-groups?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: The cmdlet was the answer which is great for the automated process. TY